# K-rank Approximation for Image Compression Using SVD (How is Storage Size Affected?)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, svd

I have a grayscale image that I run SVD on using numpy. I then create a k-rank (let's say rank 10) approximation of it and save it as an image locally. On my finder, the original grayscale image is 5 MB and the new compressed image is 2MB, showing that the compression did indeed work!

However, when I print out the original and compressed image matrix sizes, they're the same! Not sure what's going on here...

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import time

def calculate_file_size(filepath):
    return os.path.getsize(filepath)

def compress_image(input_filename, output_folder, k):
    # Construct the full path
    input_image_path = os.path.join("images", input_filename)

    image = Image.open(input_image_path)
    image_data = np.array(image)

    # Separate color channels
    channels = [image_data[:, :, i] for i in range(image_data.shape[2])]
    compressed_channels = []
    for channel in channels:
        # Reshape data for SVD
        original_shape = channel.shape
        reshaped_data = channel.reshape((-1,1))
        # Apply SVD to reshaped data
        u, s, vt = np.linalg.svd(reshaped_data, full_matrices=False)
        scopy = s.copy()
        scopy[k:] = 0.0
        compressed_data = u.dot(np.diag(scopy)).dot(vt)

        # Reshape data to the original state
        compressed_channel = compressed_data.reshape(original_shape)
        compressed_channels.append(compressed_channel)

    # Combine compressed channels back into a color image
    compressed_image_data = np.stack(compressed_channels, axis=-1)

    # Save compressed image
    compressed_image_path = os.path.join(output_folder, f"compressed_image_rank_{k}.jpg")
    Image.fromarray(compressed_image_data.astype(np.uint8)).save(compressed_image_path, "JPEG")

    original_file_size = calculate_file_size(input_image_path)
    compressed_file_size = calculate_file_size(compressed_image_path)
    print(f"Original File (Matrix) Dimensions: {image_data.shape}")
    print(f"New File (Matrix) Dimensions: {compressed_image_data.shape}")
    print(f"Original File Size: {original_file_size} bytes")
    print(f"Compressed File Size (Rank {k}): {compressed_file_size} bytes")

    percent_compression = (1 - (compressed_file_size / original_file_size)) * 100
    print(f"Percent Compression (Rank {k}): {percent_compression}%")
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).